# drawString not drawing text on window

Tags: java, string, swing, window

I'm trying to make a test window with some text on it, when I run my code, it doesn't draw the string. I specified the color for it. Can anybody help me with this?

[image: Here what it draws]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawFrame f = new DrawFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
class DrawFrame extends JFrame
 {
    public DrawFrame(){
        setTitle("For Aylin");
        setSize(1280,720);

        DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.add(panel);
    }
}

class DrawPanel extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
        g.drawString("Hi", 100, 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should override the JPanel's `paintComponent` method not its `paintComponents` method as they are for two very different purposes. The first paints the component itself (what you want) while the second gets the child components held by this parent to paint themselves.

Also remember to change the super call so that it matches, and to use the `@Override` annotation above the method.